# How does a microprocessor process an instruction set

Tags: microprocessors

For example if I have an 8085 microprocessor.

And below are the instructions.

```
MVI A, 52H : Store 32H in the accumulator

STA 4000H : Copy accumulator contents at address 4000H

HLT : Terminate program execution
```

How does the microprocessor understand the commands `MVI`, `STA`, `HLT`.

If I am correct, `HLT` has 76 as an opcode. In that case, how does a microprocessor recognize 76 as instruction rather than data?

Comment: This question is better suited for SuperUser

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "microcode".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the processor.  Some have fixed-length instructions, in which case the instruction bytes are at every <n> locations, whereas some have variable-length instructions, so that which words/bytes are opcodes and which are arguments depends on what came before.   To further complicate this, some processors have certain instructions which must be aligned or padded to certain addresses.   Yikes.

The 8085 has variable length instructions.   So you have to start at the PC and interpret each instruction based on its length to know where the next begins, and which bytes are data/arguments as opposed to opcodes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what i need to know is how does cpu know 76 is HLT and how it is processing opcode.

Comment: Well, you asked "how does a microprocessor recognize 76 as instruction rather than data" above.

The details of how the binary combinations of pin levels on the chip forming a 76 at the current PC register address and how that switches on the circuitry that corresponds to HLT and what states the circuits transition to as a result of that are due to the actual connections between the transistors of the processor itself - ie. its physical design.

Answer (score 1):

A value of 76 can represent anything, it depends on how it is being interpreted.

In the case of a micro processor, there is a special register that contains the memory address of the next instruction to execute. This data is then loaded and interpreted as an instruction to execute. If the address of the next  instruction contains the value 76, this will be interpreted as HLT (in your case). Obviously a different processor might interpret 76 as a different instruction.

On the other hand, if the data from this address is interpreted as a numerical value, it will just mean 76.

Answer (score 1):

It's just that when the processor finds 76 as a part of a program that it is executing, that is, its "program counter" points to the place in memory where the 76 is, it will interpret it as an instruction.

If the processor is then told by its program to load that same 76, from some other place in memory or even *from the same place in memory*, into a register and use it for calculations, it is interpeted as data.

This is the so called [Von Neumann architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), where program and data are stored in the same computer memory. It all looks the same, but the processor is told by its program which content to treat as data.